# vuejs props returns undefined when passing as params to router not working on component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I'm trying to pass a params on router push and then access it via props inside on component mount state but returns `undefined`, below is my attempt. Any help, idea is greatly appreciated.

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-router@2.0.0/dist/vue-router.js"></script>
```

**app.js**

```js
const router = new VueRouter({
    routes : [
      { path: '/', name : 'home', component: quotation_plans_home },
      { path : '/form', name : 'form' ,component : quotation_plans_form, props : true }
    ]
});

new Vue({
    el : '#app',
    router : router
})
```

**quotation_plans_home** component

```js
const quotation_plans_home =  {
    methods : {
        goToForm(){
            this.$router.push({ name : 'form', params : { selected_plan : 12 } });
            
        }
    },

};
```

**quotation_plans_form** component

```js
const quotation_plans_form =  {
    props : [ 'selected_plan' ],
    template  : `<div></div>`,
    mounted : function(){
        console.log( this.selected_plan );
    }
}
```

this `console.log( this.selected_plan );` returns `undefined`

Comment: try to 'console.log(this.$router.params)'

Comment: So many questions recently passing `params` that aren't defined in the URL. Why not change the `form` path to `/form/:selected_plan`?

Comment: eventually someone will want to copy-paste the url, and their expectation to land on the same page without errors wouldn't be wrong, AFAIK if you use params that might not be the case

Comment: The `props` option is not available in version 2.0.0 of vue-router. I suggest you upgrade. The latest is 3.4.6. The minimum version you need for that feature is [2.2.0](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/releases/tag/v2.2.0)